# Float indexer to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a numpy array that takes a float as a indexes (like, for example, a Pandas Series would if it had a float-type index). So let me explain. I want something like:

```
i = np.array([(5.,1), (6.,2)], dtype=[('foo', 'f4'),('bar', 'i4')])
```

if the first type (the 'foo' type), could be used as a indexer. So I could do

```
print(i[:5.5])
```

and it would print `1`, or `(5., 1)`.

I'm pretty sure that's possible with Numpy, I just don't know how to.

Comment: you want float *slicing* it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need logical indexing:

```
i[i['foo'] < 5.5]

# array([(5.0, 1)], 
#       dtype=[('foo', '<f4'), ('bar', '<i4')])
```

Answer (score 0):

`i[:5.5]` does not have an obvious meaning.

`i[:5]` means the first 5 elements of the array (or list). `i[:6]` the first 6.  What is it supposed to do with the `5.5`?  `floor(5.5)`?  Ceiling?  Return 5 and half elements?  5 elements plus a linear interpolation between the 5th and 6th?

Actually `:5.5` works (in 1.11) but with a warning:

```
In [346]: np.arange(10)[:5]
Out[346]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [347]: np.arange(10)[:5.5]
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[347]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

With your structured array, record indexing works the same way:

```
In [349]: i = np.array([(5.,1), (6.,2)], dtype=[('foo', 'f4'),('bar', 'i4')])
In [350]: i[:5]
```

It's ok to slice beyond the end - it just returns everything.

```
Out[350]: 
array([(5.0, 1), (6.0, 2)], 
      dtype=[('foo', '<f4'), ('bar', '<i4')])
In [351]: i[:5.5]
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[351]: 
array([(5.0, 1), (6.0, 2)], 
      dtype=[('foo', '<f4'), ('bar', '<i4')])
```

================

Indexing in `numpy` is just a way of counting.  There isn't an indexing or labeling list or array.  That's something that `pandas` has added, but it isn't part of `numpy`.  In your `i` array, fields do have names, e.g. `i['foo']`.  It can look like column labeling, but it's dangerous to confuse structured fields with 2d columns.